# Pass a file and variables through --extra-vars

Tags: ansible

I see that [files can supply variables to Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) through the command line using `--extra-vars "@some_file.json"`, or variables can be set in strings as key=value. Is it possible to do both? And if so, what's the syntax?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Specify both but separately.

```
--extra-vars "@some_file.json" --extra-vars "key=value"
```

Comment: thanks! now any idea what the syntax is in a Vagrantfile?
`ansible.extra_vars = '@somefile.yml'`
`ansible.extra_vars = 'key=value'` doesn't work.

Comment: Found one answer: an easy way to do this with a Vagrantfile is with `ansible.raw_arguments`.

Comment: I placed the @somefile.yaml inside the Ansible directory and upon running the playbook it worked like charm also encrypted it using ansible-vault and called it via playbook command. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using it with vagrant then here is the answer:

```
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible| 
    ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
    ansible.extra_vars = { ansible_ssh_user: 'vagrant' }
  end
```

hope this will help you.