# Ansible jinja2 template from JSON format provided as extra-vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have this jinja2 template:

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}

{% for vhost in nginx_vhosts %}
{%- if vhost.name == item.name -%}

# redirect www to non-www
server {
    listen {{ nginx_port }};
    listen [::]:{{ nginx_port }};
    port_in_redirect off;

    server_name www.{{ vhost.name }};
    return 301 http://{{ vhost.name }}$request_uri;
}
{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

An ansible role with an yaml file **vhosts.ym**l containing definitions like this:

```
nginx_vhosts:
      - name: "test1.com"
        repo: "git1"
        branch: master
        state: present
      - name: "test2.com"
        repo: "git2"
        branch: master
        state: present
...
      - name: "test101.com"
        repo: "git101"
        branch: master
        state: present
```

A task inside **playbook.yml**:

```
- name: "Generate nginx vhost configuration file"
  template:
    src: templates/nginx-vhost-template.j2
    dest: "{{ nginx_vhosts_dir }}/{{ item.name }}.conf"
    owner: "{{ nginx_user }}"
    group: "{{ nginx_group }}"
    mode: 0640
  with_items:
    - "{{ nginx_vhosts }}"
  when:
    - item.state == 'present'
  notify:
    - nginx-restart
```

I ran a taks like:

```
ansible-playbook -l web1 playbook.yml --tags=nginx-vhost-config
```

which is working fine, it will create from template a nginx vhost configuration file on the remote server as domain1.com.conf and so on for all the found definitions.

Assuming that in the vhosts.yml file I have test1.com up to test100.com, I'll add let's say test101.com and I want to run the tasks strictly for that test101.com and not for all previous hosts. So I tried something like this:

```
ansible-playbook -l web1 playbook.yml --tags=nginx-vhost-config -e "{ 'nginx_vhosts': { 'name': 'test101.com', 'state': 'present', 'repo': 'git101', 'branch': 'master' }}"
```

The issue with this is that it results in an error when trying to replace values from the jinja2 template.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'name'
```

I've also tried using **loop** instead of **with_items** but no luck.

I understand that when using the extra-vars, the provided content is in JSON format but I was not able to find a different way to pass the content from vhosts.yml as extra vars for one single entry. Is there any way to make this functional?

Is there a better approach maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959691/pass-a-file-and-variables-through-extra-vars?

Comment: not really. I've tried several methods. I don't see any difference between passing the JSON content as extra arg on command line or load it from a .json file. The issue is that when using the JSON content as extra vars, the template taks fails. I haven't found any other way to specify as extra vars only a specific content from that vhosts.yml file (except for the JSON) format

Comment: You have a simple typo; your in-file `nginx_hosts:` is a **list** but your `-e` version is a `dict`; simply wrap your `{}` in `[]` and it'll likely start to work for you